# convert string into sequential array in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I want to convert this string: `["5b09e23972929.png", "5b0a7f1361a00.png"]` that I get from my MySQL database into an sequential array. The reason is I want to remove single parts of the string. So `$string[0]` should have the value `5b09e23972929.png` is this case.

Comment: How did that get into your DB? You shouldn't store structured content like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = json_decode('["5b09e23972929.png", "5b0a7f1361a00.png"]');
```

Comment: That code generates the Notice Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: I think you forgot the quotes